# Install Flask in Python 3.4+ NOT for python2.7

Tags: python, flask, dependencies, virtualenv

So, I know how to actually install flask, via `pip install Flask`

But, I'm running a virtualenv with `python3.4`. The problem is, Flask is in fact installed. The problem is though, it is installed for `python2.7` and not `python3.4` .

I did run this command with the virtualenv activated via `source bin/activate` , but it seems to install it for `python2.7` even though a virtualenv running `python3.4` is activated.

How do I fix this? im pulling my hair out over this.

Thanks

Comment: `pip3` , `pip3.4` ?

Comment: The environment is python3.4.

Comment: you should have commands `pip3` and `pip3.4` to install for `python3.4`

Comment: I tried, this, this doesnt work.

Comment: `python3.4 -m pip install Flask` ?

Comment: Yes, it installs it, but then i try the python interpreter `import Flask` or `from flask import Flask` and both return `ImportError: No module named 'flask'`

Comment: do you run it with `python3.4 script.py` ? maybe you run it as Python 2 - you can use script with `print(sys.version)` to check it

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.3, you can use venv instead of virtualenv (see [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)). If you do so, running `source bin/activate` will set python command to  python 3 and use the right pip.

you can create the environnement using:

```
python3 -m venv myEnvName
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm just switch to python 3, and there is a list of packages installed. Hit add(+), and look for flask

You can switch to python 3 by hitting file-> setting -> Project:Projectname -> Project Interpreter